# KDevelop proxy setting

Tags: kdevelop

I'm running KDevelop 4.7.1 on centOs 7. I can't seem to access things like the KDevelop Add-on providers, probably because I am behind a proxy. Is there a way to configure the proxy settings to access the provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, KDevelop uses whatever proxy settings were set up in the Konqueror web browser. Setting those correctly allowed access to the add-on providers.

Comment: Yes, KDevelop uses KDE's system-wide proxy settings